Detecting Docker Compose success in GitLab CI pipeline
I'm having some trouble with the docker container deployment in the GitLab CI pipeline. Please see my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.9'
services:
  MY_DOCKER_SERVICE_NAME:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '${WEB_SERVER_PORT}:${WEB_SERVER_PORT}'
    environment:
      - PORT=${WEB_SERVER_PORT}
      - MONGODB_URL=${MONGODB_URL}

volumes:
  mongo-data:

and my summarised .gitlab-ci.yml:
image: node:18-alpine

stages:
  - prepare
  - lint
  - build
  - deploy

// Removed unrelavent parts

build_app:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker compose build --no-cache

deploy_app:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker compose up 

I've tried to use varying docker compose commands like below in the deploy stage:

Using docker compose up, causes the pipeline stuck in the running state after even a successful deployment
Using docker compose up -d causes the pipeline to finish without waiting for the container, leading to even failed deployments being marked as successful.
Using docker compose --exit-code-from=MY_DOCKER_SERVICE_NAME works great in the failure scenarios but it also stuck in the running state after successful deployments
And it's not possible to use -d flag with the --exit-code-from flag

but they're all not working as expected. Is there any way to detect the correct container status and behave as expected in the GitLab CI?
P.S. Used process.exit(1) to simulate failure application scenarios

In contrast to the (old) docker-compose command, the (new) docker compose command has a --wait argument for this. Might be helpful to implement a health check as well.

After a long time, I'm answering my own question.
Based on Klause D's comment, I developed the following method: use the --wait flag during the Docker Compose phase. This ensures that Docker Compose waits for the completion of the health check stages:
deploy_app:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - docker compose up -d --wait

Then, implement health check process in your Docker compose:
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:${WEB_SERVER_PORT}/health-check"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 5
  start_period: 5s

This way, pipeline will wait for the health check period to end and will end up with the desired behavior.
